# Accidental S3 Object deletion; Recover deleted object from the Cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hypothetically, if I accidentally delete an S3 object that is in use by Cloudfront, can I retrieve that object via Cloudfront when the Cloudfront cache is not cleared and the object isn't invalidated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe. You may still be able to ask for the object via http/https until any one of the following occurs:

- The object's time-to-live expires,
- The distribution is invalidated, or
- The object is evicted by the cache to make room for other objects

But all of this assumes the object was in the cache to begin with. Don't rely on any of this though.

There are a few ways to handle deleted objects in S3:

1. Enable versioning on your S3 bucket. When object versioning is enabled, old versions of the object are preserved. If you delete an object, you can still retrieve the previous version from S3.

Note, that you'll be paying for the storage of all versions of all objects (even deleted objects). You can use s3 bucket lifecycles to delete old versions after a pre-determined time to reduce these costs.

More information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

2. Enable MFA-on-delete on your bucket. When this is enabled, it's much harder to delete objects since you'll have to enter an MFA password to make the delete happen.

More information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMFADelete.html

3. Apply a bucket policy to your bucket that prevents deleting of objects.

Here's an example policy:

```
{
  "Id": "ExamplePolicyId12345678",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmtSid12345678",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-example-com",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/226700/how-do-i-prevent-deletion-of-s3-buckets

Comment: *Until the object's time-to-live expires (or the distribution is invalidated)* or the object is otherwise evicted from the cache, which can happen at any time, for example, to make room for more popular objects.  While theoretically possible, this should not be part of a strategy, since dumb luck would be a major determinant of success.  +1 for versioning and mfa delete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will indeed enable versioning for my buckets, but we both know objects created before I enable versioning aren't versioned, it's those objects I'm concerned about.

Comment: Not quite true. Old versions cannot be recovered from before versioning was enabled. But versions present in the bucket at the start of versioning can be recovered. So if you enable versioning today, then today's versions are safe.